# MariaDB server error on Update command sql

Tags: java, sql, mariadb

Im trying to update one value in a row and when I run the program I get the error :

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id = 1.

I have tried changing my Update statement but I do not know why the error is happening.

```
                Player updatedPlayer = null;
                System.out.println("Enter the player ID:");
                String playerId = FileUtility.getInput().nextLine();

                System.out.println("Here are the players");
                //theList = loadCampersFromDatabase(theList);
                for (Player players : PlayerDAO.selectAllById(playerId)) {
                    System.out.println(players);
                    System.out.println("Enter the new amount paid");
                    newAmount = FileUtility.getInput().nextInt();

                    Connection dbConnection = null;
                    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

                    String updateTableSQL = "UPDATE Player SET WHERE id = ?, firstName = ?, lastName = ?, parentsName= ?, phoneNumber= ?, email = ?, amountPaid = ?";


                    try {
                        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
                        preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(updateTableSQL);

                        preparedStatement.setInt(1, players.getRegistrationId());
                        preparedStatement.setString(2, players.getFirstName());
                        preparedStatement.setString(3, players.getLastName());
                        preparedStatement.setString(4, players.getParentsName());
                        preparedStatement.setInt(5, players.getPhoneNumber());
                        preparedStatement.setString(6, players.getEmail());
                        preparedStatement.setInt(7, players.getAmountPaid());

                        // execute update SQL stetement
                        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

                        System.out.println("Record is updated to DBUSER table!");

                    } catch (SQLException e) {

                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

                    } finally {

                        if (preparedStatement != null) {
                            preparedStatement.close();
                        }

                        if (dbConnection != null) {
                            dbConnection.close();
                        }

                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this i guess:

```
String updateTableSQL = "UPDATE Player SET  firstName = ?, lastName = ?, parentsName= ?, phoneNumber= ?, email = ?, amountPaid = ? WHERE id = ?";


                    try {
                        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
                        preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(updateTableSQL);

                        preparedStatement.setString(1, players.getFirstName());
                        preparedStatement.setString(2, players.getLastName());
                        preparedStatement.setString(3, players.getParentsName());
                        preparedStatement.setInt(4, players.getPhoneNumber());
                        preparedStatement.setString(5, players.getEmail());
                        preparedStatement.setInt(6, players.getAmountPaid());
                     preparedStatement.setInt(7,players.getRegistrationId());
                        // execute update SQL stetement
                        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

                        System.out.println("Record is updated to DBUSER table!");

                    } catch (SQLException e) {

                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

                    }
```